# Why should I use a ContentProvider with exported=false?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-database

I can't figure out why I should use a ContentProvider with the setting `"android:exported=false"` in the AndroidManifest.xml. Aren't ContentProviders created to share data between multiple applications? In this way, I am restricting data sharing only to my application and not to external applications. But at this point I can simply use a database in SQLite (maybe with SQLiteOpenHelper).

In the case where I need to create a pre-populated database by loading data from a Rest API, but at the same time I do not need to share my data to other applications, should I create a ContentProvider with the setting `"android:exported=false"` using the ContentProviderOperation and ContentProviderOperation.Builder Classes (I have seen that these two Classes are used for massive data insertion) ? Or should I create a database in SQLite and insert the data using the `INSERT` command ?

Thank you!